# How to open a new blank window using webdriver in java.

Tags: selenium, webdriver, driver

I am using (Webdriver) driver.close(to close the browser instead of using driver.quit). 
After the browser window is closed i am not able to use driver.get(url) -which throws unreachableBrowserException.

As a work around i am trying to get windowHandles.size(), when it is zero i want to open a new blank window and then use driver.get(url).

But i cound'not find any methods to open a blank window in Webdriver class.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code..what ever the browser you user. use it like this after the closing the current browser session.

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver()/firefoxdriver();
driver.get("Url");
```

Comment: This creates a browser profile everytime we use driver = new driver, that is what we are currently doing...it seems inefficient. Any other way of just closing the browser rather than to create a new driver everytime?

Comment: Web driver behaves like this only. it will not work as just closing the browser and open the new browser in the same driver session. Here when the browser is closed means, the driver session in web driver is closed and has to create new instance of the web driver.

Answer (score 0):

Once it's quit, the browser is gone - you are left with a `driver` instance that is unusable.

Unless you declare a new instance and assign it back to it. For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("a"); // doing something
driver.Quit(); // test is over, closing the browser
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // you will need to give it a new driver to work with.
```

Comment: then what is the use of driver.close() - just to close the browser window?. Its basically same as the driver.quit().?

Comment: As you test an app it can open windows on its own such as with JavaScript. You'll use `driver.switchTo().window()` in those cases to switch to the newly opened window. `driver.close()` closes that newly opened window and then you'll call `driver.switchTo().window()` again to get back to the previous window. So `close()` closes a window, `quit()` quits the driver which in the process closes all windows and stops the instance of the driver